# Firebase Analytics ITEM_ID vs CONTENT_TYPE

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my iOS app, I'm using the following Firebase Analytics function call:

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventSelectContent, parameters: [
    AnalyticsParameterItemID: "id-button",
    AnalyticsParameterContentType: "button"]
)
```

I know I can put any `String` for the ItemID and ContentType parameters, but what's the intended use for each of these parameters? How are they supposed to be different?